# LINQ request for getting the furthest xml child node with an attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that defines item/location categories, and their id's like follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Eve_App>
    <Item_Types>
        <Ore>
            <Arkonor>
                <Arkonor ID="22"/>
                <Compressed_Arkonor ID="28367"/>
                <Compressed_Crimson_Arkonor ID="28385"/>
                <Compressed_Prime_Arkonor ID="28387"/>
                <Crimson_Arkonor ID="17425"/>
                <Prime_Arkonor ID="17426"/>
            </Arkonor>

            <Bistot>
                <Bistot ID="1223"/>
                <Compressed_Bistot ID="28388"/>
                <Compressed_Monoclinic_Bistot ID="28389"/>
                <Compressed_Triclinic_Bistot ID="28390"/>
                <Monoclinic_Bistot ID="17429"/>
                <Triclinic_Bistot ID="17428"/>
            </Bistot>

            <Crokite>
                <Compressed_Crokite ID="28391"/>
                <Compressed_Crystalline_Crokite ID="28392"/>
                <Compressed_Sharp_Crokite ID="28393"/>
                <Crokite ID="1225"/>
                <Crystalline_Crokite ID="17433"/>
                <Sharp_Crokite ID="17432"/>
            </Crokite>
            ...
        </Ore>

        <Ice>
            <Blue_Ice ID="16264"/>
            <CLear_Icicle ID="16262"/>
            <Compressed_Blue_Ice ID="28433"/>
            ...
        </Ice>

        <Gas>
            <Booster_Gas_Clouds>
                <Amber_Cytoserocin ID="25268"/>
                <Amber_Mykoserocin ID="28694"/>
                <Azure_Cytoserocin ID="25279"/>
                <Azure_Mykoserocin ID="28695"/>
                <Celadon_Cytoserocin ID="25275"/>
                <Celadon_Mykoserocin ID="28696"/>
                ...
            </Booster_Gas_Clouds>

            <Fullerenes>
                <Fullerite_C28 ID="30375"/>
                <Fullerite_C32 ID="30376"/>
                ...
            </Fullerenes>
        </Gas>

        <Mineral>
            <Isogen ID="37"/>
            <Megacyte ID="40"/>
            <Mexallon ID="36"/>
            <Morphite ID=""/>
            <Nocxium ID="38"/>
            <Pyerite ID="35"/>
            <Tritanium ID="34"/>
            <Zydrine ID="39"/>
        </Mineral>
...
```

As you can see, the items containing the `ID` are not necessarily on the same level. I would like to know if there is a LINQ request that would get me the name of the node associated with the `ID` that I would want independently of the level of that item in the `Item_Types` node.

EDIT:

Would the following request work in that it would iterate inside all of the nested children nodes?

```
IEnumerable<string> ids =
       from el in xelement.Elements("Item_Types")
       where (int)el.Attribute("ID") == "22" // For example
       select (string)el.value;
```

EDIT2:

For the moment I have this:

```
IEnumerable<String> names = _xmlFile.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID") && uint.Parse(x.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID").Value) == id)
    .Select(t => t.Name.LocalName);

if (names.Count() != 0) // Error here
{
    return names.ElementAt(0);
}
else
{
    return "";
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when calling the `Count()` function:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I can see this error in debug when I look at the value of the `names` variable too. This does not happen though when I just `return names.ElementAt(0);` without using `Count()` (I am able to see the name associated to that `ID` properly), but then if the `ID` doesn't exist, I get another error when I try to `return names.ElementAt(0);` (thus why I do that check).

Why is it that I get the mentioned `Parse()` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    IEnumerable<string> ids = xelement.Descendants()
.Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID") && x.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID").Value == "28390")
.Select(t => t.Name.LocalName);
```

First I check in descendant nodes that ID attribute exists and if it is I check it's value for ID needed.

Comment: So basically `Descendants` gives us access to all the child nodes of the root element, and the query check each one of those nodes?

Comment: Just wanted to add that in order for this answer to work, you have to parse `x.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID").Value` as an `int` (with `Parse()` or `TryParse()`). For some reason though, I keep getting the following error: `Input string was not in a correct format`. This does not affect me (the request does find the name associated to the ID and I can return the `IEnumerable.ElementAt(0)`), but if I use `IEnumerable.Count` the error pops up and crashes my app.

Comment: @Choub890 not sure where you put .Count. Can you post a bit of code and tell, where the error pops out?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't very clearly stated in question (I think an example of expected output would clarify this), but assuming that you want to get element name where `ID` attribute equals certain value and the target element can be at any level depth in the XML document, you can use [`Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like so :

```
IEnumerable<string> names =
       from el in xelement.Descendants()
       where (int)el.Attribute("ID") == "22"
       select (string)el.Name.LocalName;
```

`(int)el.Attribute("ID")` simply return `0` -instead of throwing exception- in case there is no `ID` attribute in current `el`, so you can skip checking existence of `ID` attribute.

Comment: This was indeed what I wanted, thanks! If I know that the items are children of the `<Item_Types>` node, can I specify `xelement.Descendants("Item_Types")`? For some reason doing this return 0 elements all the time.