# Input string was not in a correct format error, but still able to get parsed value from LINQ to XML query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file from which I go get `ID`s from certain nodes. The nodes have the following structure:

```
<Bistot ID="1223"/>
<Compressed_Bistot ID="28388"/>
<Compressed_Monoclinic_Bistot ID="28389"/>
...
```

They are also at different levels in my xml file (it is too big to list it all here).

In order to do this, I use a function that executes a LINQ query:

```
public String GetItemName(uint id)
{
    IEnumerable<String> names = _xmlFile.Descendants()
        .Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID") && uint.Parse(x.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID").Value) == id)
        .Select(t => t.Name.LocalName);

    return names.ElementAt(0);
}
```

In this form, it works well if the `id` I provide exists and the `names` variable actually has an entry. If it doesn't though, it raises an exception at `return names.ElementAt(0);` because there is no elements at index `0`. At this point, in debug mode, if I go check the variable `names`, I do see it mentioned that `Input string was not in a correct format`, but no error is *raised* and the function returns the good `name` associated to `id`.

I have also tried the following form in order to remove the exception that occurs if the LINQ request doesn't find any associated names in the xml file:

```
public String GetItemName(uint id)
{
    IEnumerable<String> names = _xmlFile.Descendants()
        .Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID") && uint.Parse(x.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID").Value) == id)
        .Select(t => t.Name.LocalName);

    if (names.Count() != 0)  // Error raised here
    {
        return names.ElementAt(0);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is where my problem occurs, since in this case, when I call `names.Count()`, the `Input string was not in a correct format`(of type `FormatException`) error is raised and my application then does not continue/complete.

I have also tried to call `.ToList()` at the end of my LINQ query as I had a warning telling me to do so. But in this case, the `Input string was not in a correct format` error is raised inside my LINQ query directly, and not at the `names.Count()` call.

I do understand the nature of this error, something is not getting parsed right when I call `uint.Parse(x.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID").Value)` inside my LINQ query, but I don't understand why for two reasons:

1. I have manually checked and each values in the `ID` attribute in my xml file are real `uint` (just numbers, no spaces, etc).
2. When not using `names.Count()` or `.ToList()`, while it does mention the error in debug mode when I look at the variable, the name associated to the `id` is still found and the function returns it properly.

Why is my `uint.Parse(...)` giving me troubles here?

Comment: As an aside, do you really need to be using LocalName-matching only? Might there be ID attributes in multiple namespaces?

Comment: The LINQ query itself was actually provided from another question I asked yesterday: [LINQ request for getting the furthest xml child node with an attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658512/linq-request-for-getting-the-furthest-xml-child-node-with-an-attribute), so I was directly using what was provided to me in that answer (though it is now giving me the above mentioned error). I decided create this question in order to resolve this. Using just `a.Name` and `t.Name` directly, VS is telling me that it can't convert `List<XName>` to `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you use `ElementAt(0)`, it only needs to find the first element - so if there's an `ID` element later with an invalid value (which I'm sure there is), you're not going to hit it. When you call `Count()` or `ToList()`, it iterates over the *whole* of the query, causing the problem.

As it is, your code is very inefficient though, evaluating multiple times - it would be much better written as:

```
public String GetItemName(uint id)
{
    IEnumerable<String> names = ...; // Query as before
    return names.FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
}
```

I'd also recommend using the explicit conversions provided by LINQ to XML instead of manually calling `uint.Parse`, too:

```
IEnumerable<String> names = _xmlFile.Descendants()
    .Where(x => (uint?) x.Attributes()
                         .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID")
                         .FirstOrDefault() == id)
    .Select(t => t.Name.LocalName);
```

Here we're finding the first `ID` attribute, converting it to `uint?` (giving `null` if there's no such attribute) and then comparing that with `id`.

Comment: This works, though when I debug in VS, I still see the error mention in the variable under the following tree: `names` -> `ResultView` -> `base`. Is this normal?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work when I give an ID that isn't in my xml file, I still get that same error raised, which crashes my application.

Comment: Don't need linq solution : return (names == null)? string.Empty : names;

Comment: @Choub890: Well yes, it would, because your data is still broken, and it's still looking through the whole file. You still need to find the `ID` attribute that's got a bad value.

Comment: @jdweng: `names` will never be null though. It will be an empty sequence if there are no matches.

Comment: It was indeed a bad data that didn't have an ID. Guess I'll never make that assumption again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you are getting an error due to returning a null sequence as a string.  This need to be fixed.  I thought an empty sequence is a null.  It is fine to return the null, just make sure the main method checks for the empty string.

Comment: @jdweng: What do you mean by "you are getting an error"? I'm not getting any error - and I'm not returning a null sequence as a string. I don't know what you think is wrong with the code (you're not being very clear) but the code I've given should be fine.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  Thought string.Empty was still causing an issue.  To make your code robust, I would still assume that somebody will pass this method an ID that doesn't exist and in that case either implement an exception or return string.Empty.

Comment: @hdweng I *am* returning an empty string in that case - that's what `?? ""` does.